# Custom translator cannot extract contents of XLIFF file

Tags: microsoft-translator, xliff

The XLIFF (version 2.0) files I upload for training the custom translator always come up with the same error: "Failed to extract the contents of the uploaded file."

I used a schema to ensure the formatting of the file is correct and simplified it to 1 translation but it still doesn't work. This is what the file looks like:

```
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0" version="2.0" srcLang="en-US" trgLang="es-ES">
 <file id="f1" original="Graphic Example.psd">
  <skeleton href="Graphic Example.psd.skl"/>
      <unit id="1">
      <segment>
        <source>Calculating...</source>
        <target>Calculando...</target>
      </segment>
    </unit>
 </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently support Xliff 2.0.  It's something that we want to add in very soon, but currently we only support version 1.2 and older.