# Uploading Business Central Base App.xlf results in "Failed to extract the contents of the uploaded file."

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator, dynamics-business-central

I try to upload the Base App.xlf file from English into German (by Business Central 15), but everytime I upload the file, I receive an error that says "Failed to extract the contents of the uploaded file." after 2-3 minutes. If I upload a smaller .xlf file, everything is fine.

Base App.xlf: 62.25Mb
Smaller file: 74Kb

Both files are written in xliff version 1.2. Regarding to the post below, Custom Translator supports it in 2018.
[Custom translator cannot extract contents of XLIFF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404504/custom-translator-cannot-extract-contents-of-xliff-file)

I can't figure out, why the bigger file is not processed. Some more information would be useful. Is this error thrown cause of special character?

Comment: you can email custommt@microsoft.com with the details of your file/workspace to get a more detailed error.

Comment: Thank you, will have that in mind, but i already could figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I just figuered out that the Base Application has some missing -tags in the -tags, which leads to the error, obviously. I used an xlst-File to delete tags with missing . This deleted -tags with an empty -tag, too.